# T-SQL Sum IIf query

Tags: sql, sum

```
    SELECT t1.detail_Date AS clmDate
    ,t1.detail_agentID AS clmPID
    ,t3.HODCode AS clmHOD
    ,t1.detail_CallsHandled AS clmIBConnects
    ,t1.detail_TalkTime AS clmIBTalk
    ,t1.detail_WrapTime AS clmIBWrap
    ,t1.detail_HoldTime AS clmIBHold
    ,t1.detail_HandleTime AS clmIBTotal
    ,Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute.Value] = [Inbound],0)) AS clmIBConnects
--  ,Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute] = "Inbound", [clmTalk], 0)) AS IBTalk
--  ,Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute] = "Inbound", [clmWrap], 0)) AS IBWrap
--  ,Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute] = "Inbound", [clmTalk] + [clmWrap] + [clmHold], 0)) AS IBTotal
    ,Sum(0) AS clmOBSignedOn
    ,Sum(0) AS Preview
    ,Sum(0) AS OBTalk
    ,Sum(0) AS OBUpdate
    ,Sum(0) AS OBWork
    ,Sum(0) AS OBConnects
--  ,Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute] = "Inbound", [clmHold], 0)) AS IBHold
--  ,Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute] = "Outbound", [clmHold], 0)) AS OBHold}
```

I am not getting the sum(iif.. part of the queries more specifically:
`,Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute] = "Inbound", [clmIBConnects], 0)) AS clmIBConnects`

it shows invalid column name 'Inbound' invalid column name 'clmIBConnects'?

`fldCallRoute` column is in table `t2` which has the entries Inbound so I'm not sure why its saying a column name inbound?

Comment: You do realize that `Sum(0)` is always `0`, right? also, you are missing the 3rd argument of the `iif` function in `IIf([fldCallRoute.Value] = [Inbound],0)`.

Comment: Yes sum(0) as those are not being used but they still want it displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need single quotes for string constants:

```
Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute] = 'Inbound', [clmTalk], 0)) AS IBTalk,
```

I have a preference for `case` over `iif()`.  `case` is ANSI standard and available in almost all databases:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN fldCallRoute = 'Inbound' THEN clmTalk ELSE 0 END) as IBTalk,
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quote `'` for a string . Double quotes `"` indicate a column , usually used for reserved words :

```
,Sum(IIf([fldCallRoute] = 'Inbound', [clmIBConnects], 0)) AS clmIBConnects
```

You also have 6 columns being evaluated as `Sum(0)` , which is always `0` .. Typo?